# Finding the maximum number of points where the distance between each pair of points is at least d

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, data-structures

I have a set of points `{p1,p2,...,pn}`. I want to find the maximum number of points in this set that satisfies that the distance (Euclidean distance) between each pair of points is at least `d`.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what problems did you have with the implementation?

Comment: If you consider the graph of the relation "distance at least d", your problem is in fact the maximum clique problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Finding_a_single_maximal_clique

Comment: Either the points are 1-dimensional and the problem is trivial, or they are 2+ dimensional and it's NP-complete. The latter case, in 2D, is called the [maximum independent set for unit disk graphs](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9090358O). However, it can be [approximated efficiently.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_disk_graph)

Comment: @kcsquared Thank you. Your response is much appreciated. 
Yes, the points are located in 2D dimensional space. I tried many greedy approaches but none of them had lead me to optimal solution.

Comment: @kcsquared I also thought of a Brute force solution. But the cost of it will be huge as I think it would be O(n!)

Answer (score 0):

You need to read through the set of points from the first element to the (last element - 1)
then, you calculate the distance between these two points with this formula :
**sqrt(pow(x2-x1,2)+pow(y2-y1,2))** where **(x1,y1)** is a point and **(x2,y2)** is the following point of the set.
If this distance equals at least **d**, then you increment the variable which counts the number of points you want.

(Sorry but my english is very bad)
Do you need an example ? I can do it in Python3

```py
from math import sqrt

x_points = [3,5.2,7,1,0,9.8,5]
y_points = [0,2,8,4,7,1,1.2]

# There are 7 points
# (x_points[0];y_points[0]) is the point (3;0)

min_distance = 3
max_number_count = 0

for i in range(0,len(x_points)-1):
    if sqrt(pow(x_points[i]-x_points[i+1],2)+pow(y_points[i]-y_points[i+1],2)) >= min_distance:
        max_number_count+=1
```

The result is **max_number_count**

Comment: This seems to solve the problem of ‘count how many adjacent points in the list are distance at least d’, rather than the maximum set of points such that **all** pairs in the set are at distance at least d